# How to filter a .mdb Access Database using TAdoTable.Filter

Tags: delphi, ms-access-2010

I have a `TADOConnection` with a `TADOTable`, and I want to filter the table for professions containing or starting with a character the user types into a `TEdit` on the Form. Here is the code I am currently using:

```pascal
procedure TfrmProfessions.Filter;
begin
  if edtSearch.text = '' then
  begin
    dmPAT.ADOTable1.filtered := false;
  end
  else
  begin
    with dmPAT.ADOTable1 do
    begin
      filtered := false;
      Filter := 'Profession LIKE ' + quotedstr(edtSearch.text + '%');
      filtered := true;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I have an Access Violation at this line and I don't know how to solve it:

```pascal
dmPAT.ADOTable1.filtered := false;
```

I suspect this is because, in the `OnCreate` event of the Form, I clear the `TEdit` and it calls this `Filter procedure` before the `TADOTable` object is created, though I am not sure.

Another error I'm getting is `Cannot convert type(Null) to type(String)`. I get this when I set the filter, and it filters, but there is no record matching the filter. How do I solve this?

Comment: 1) I strongly recommend you drop the habit of using `with`.  The minimal amount of typing time you might save is unlikely to compensate for the hours you may spend later on, looking for obscure bugs caused by using `with`.  2)  Is your dmPat being auto-created before your TfrmProfessions?  If not, make sure that it is.

Comment: @MartynA How would I do that? Also, how do I solve the problem with the filter when there are null records?

Comment: For autocreation order, go to View | Tool windows |projects in the IDE and it should show you the units containing  your datamodule & form.  Drag the datamodule unit *carefully* above the other one.  See where that gets you with your errors.  Next, have you created persistent TFields for your table? (By rigt-clicking it and selecting `Fields editor`from the pop-up)

Comment: @MartynA I managed to fix the first error, which was an `Access Violation. I edited my question because I realised now that the second error is not an AV, but a `Cannot convert Type(Null) to Type(String)` error.

Comment: Well done.  Yes, the second error is an exception rather than an AV  AFAIK, it shouldn't happen and I have a feeling that the fact that it is may be Access-specific.  I don't usually use Access but I'll see if I can set up a test mdb overnight.  Later ...

Comment: Before I forget, aside from anything else, if you want the filter to match fields containing what the user has typed, you need a % wildcard before the edtSEarchText as well as after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

At the start of your procedure `TfrmProfessions.Filter`, add these lines

```
Caption := dmPat.AdoTable1.FieldByName('Profession').ClassName;  // the purpose of this is 
//  so that you can tell at a glance what field type your Professions field is. which could be important

Assert(Assigned(dmPat));  //  Assert generates an exception if its argument is false
//  so this checks that dmPat has been created
Assert(Assigned(dmPat.AdoTable1));  //  checks that dmPat.AdoTable1 has been created.
Assert(dmPat.AdoTable1.Active);  // checks that the table is open
```

That much ought to flush out any problems with the db objects not having been created.

**Update** I gather from your comments that you have solved your exception
problem and look forward to reading how you did it.  Meanwhile, I have been
writing the following and decided to post it as it might give you and others some insight
into how to go about investigating problems like the ones you reported.

I starteds a new VCL in D10.4.2 and added to the main form a TAdoConnection,  a TAdoTable, a TADoCommand, a TDataSource
connected to AdoTable1, a TDBGrid and TDBNavigator connected to the DataSource and a TEdit for the search text,
plus a few TButtons to invoke the routines below.  I didn't bother with
putting the TAdoTable etc into a TDataModule because I've already mentioned how to deal with that.

I then created a test Access db with a Text field called AName and a Number one called ANumber, using
the following code

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if AdoTable1.Active then
    AdoTable1.Close;
  AdoCommand1.CommandText :=

{.$define DropTable}
{$ifdef DropTable}
  'Drop table MATest';
{$else}
  'CREATE TABLE MATest (AName Char(12) , ANumber NUMBER)';
{$endif}

  AdoCommand1.Execute;
end;
```

The `$ifdef` was so that I could easily drop the table and start again.

The "received wisdom" in internet
groups seems to be that to create an Access table in Delphi code, you need to use the AdoX
ActiveX library, which is separate from the Ado access components.  However, the  TAdoCommand is perfectly capable of doing it.

Then, I added a few records to it using this procedure:

```
procedure TForm1.InsertData;
begin
  ADoTable1.Open;

  AdoTable1.InsertRecord(['aaa']);
  AdoTable1.InsertRecord(['abb']);
  AdoTable1.InsertRecord(['bbb']);
end;
```

Notice that this deliberately does not specify a value for the second, ANumber, field, so in the database file, the ANumber
field should receive whatever value Access uses for a missing value (which I would expect to
be Null, but whatever.

Btw when investigating problems, I always create the new records in code, so that the
values stay the same in each run of the program and to save me thinking up data to type in.

Then I added this AfterScroll event for AdoTable1

```
procedure TForm1.ADOTable1AfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  F : TField;
  S : String;
begin
  F := AdoTable1.Fields[0];
  S := F.AsString;
  F := AdoTable1.Fields[1];
  S := S + ' / ' + F.AsString;
  Caption := S;
end;
```

The point of this was to force re-evaluation of the string representation of both
fields to see if scrolling around the table provoked the exception you've been getting.
Result: No exceptions encountered.

I then added the following code to set up filtering

```
procedure TForm1.edtSearchChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UpdateFilter;
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateFilter;
begin
  Assert(AdoTable1.Active);  // checks that the table is open
  AdoTable1.Filtered := False;  //  we should turn filtering off whether or not
  //  edSearchText.Text is blank or not

  if Trim(edtSearch.Text) <> '' then begin  //  Trim() removes leading and trailing blanks
    AdoTable1.Filter := 'AName LIKE ' + quotedstr('%' + edtSearch.Text + '%');
    AdoTable1.Filtered := True;
  end;
end;
```

and that works fine.  A filter of `aa` matches the first two rowa and `b` matches the second and third rows.  The ADO `Filter` property is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/filter-property-ado).

QED.  I hope that this example shows that it can be far easier to investigate problems like the ones you've had by building a test project step-by-step rather than trying to debug a completed project.

Investigating all this, I noticed something abooout ADO which I noticed some time ago:  Delphi TAdo components access databases via the MDAC (Microsoft Data Access Components) layer in Windows and after certain database operations fail in a way which generates an exception in the MDAC layer, the layer behaves erratically until Windows is restarted.  I'm pretty sure that I ran into this here, because after I had tried filtering successfully, some error or other occurred, and after that I simply could not get Ado filtering to work (it always produced empty results) *until* I restarted Windows.  After that, it went back to working correctly.

**Update 2**

There is one lingering question.  Why is is that if a TDBEdit is connected to my
ANumber field (or your Hours one), it works fine, yet if we transfer the field value
manually inti a TEdit or TSpinEdit, we get the string-conversion exception?  I get
it with this code

```
procedure TForm1.DataSource1DataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
begin
  sedNumber.Text := AdoTable1.FieldByName('ANumber').Value;
end;
```

The answer is to be found in the source code of TDBedit in the Vcl.DBCtrls unit:

```
procedure TDBEdit.DataChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FDataLink.Field <> nil then
  begin
    [...]
    if FFocused and FDataLink.CanModify then
      Text := FDataLink.Field.Text
    else
    begin
      EditText := FDataLink.Field.DisplayText;
      if FDataLink.Editing and FDataLink.FModified then
        Modified := True;
    end;
  end [...]
```

Notice this does not access the field's `Value`, but rather its `Text` or `DisplayText` property
and that's the answer.  So a somewhat more concise fix than your one is simply to do

```
procedure TForm1.DataSource1DataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
begin
  sedNumber.Text := AdoTable1.FieldByName('ANumber').Text;
end;
```

and that silences the exceptions without any explicit Null checks.  It works because

```
procedure TFloatField.GetText
```

in Data.DB explicitly returns an empty string as the `Text` value when the field contain a Null.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help once again! I will make note of the above code. I have found the rather simple and stupid error for the `delphi Could not convert type(Null) to type(string)`. I will share my answer below in a few hours after school.

Comment: Glad you found it and please do share it later.

Answer (score 0):

So I traced the problem. In the `OnDataChange` event in my `DataModule` I have a call to this procedure:

```
procedure TdmPAT.DataSource1DataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
begin
  frmProfessions.Show_Record_Values;
end;
```

Here is the procedure in the form with the `DBGrid`:

```pascal
procedure TfrmProfessions.Show_Record_Values;
begin
  with dmPAT.ADOTable1 do
  begin
    sedPK.value := FieldByName('PK').value;
    sedHours.value := FieldByName('Hours').value;

    edtProfession.text := fields[1].value;
    edtCost.text := floattostrf(FieldByName('Cost').AsFloat, ffcurrency, 12, 2);

    if FieldByName('Popular').asboolean then
      rgpPopular.ItemIndex := 0
    else
      rgpPopular.ItemIndex := 1;
  end;
end;
```

Now the problem comes in once I filtered the `DBGrid`. It's not the filter itself, but it causes a record to be displayed with Null values. Then when I try to display the active record (null record) in the edits, delphi cannot convert Null to String at the line: `sedHours.value:=FieldByName('Hours').value;`

That's why I get the errors. XD Some try clauses should solve the issue.
***I have redone the code of the above procedure and it solved the problem***

```pascal
procedure TfrmProfessions.Show_Record_Values;
var
  Profession, Hours, Cost, Popular: Tfield;
begin
  Profession := dmPAT.ADOTable1.fields[1];
  Hours := dmPAT.ADOTable1.fields[2];
  Cost := dmPAT.ADOTable1.fields[3];
  Popular := dmPAT.ADOTable1.fields[4];

  // check if null values
  if Profession.value = Null then
    edtProfession.text := ''
  else
    edtProfession.text := Profession.value;

  if Hours.value = Null then //The Hours Field is an Integer.
    sedHours.value := 0 //sedHours is a TSpinEdit.
  else
    sedHours.value := Hours.value;

  if Cost.value = Null then //The Cost field is Currency in MSAccess.
    edtCost.text := floattostrf(0, ffcurrency, 12, 2)
  else
    edtCost.text := floattostrf(Cost.value, ffcurrency, 12, 2);

  if Popular.value = Null then
  begin
    rgpPopular.ItemIndex := -1;
  end
  else
  begin
    case Popular.asboolean of
      true:
        rgpPopular.ItemIndex := 0;
      false:
        rgpPopular.ItemIndex := 1;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @MartynA, I don't know why I didn't think of it sooner. And yes, `with` clauses are dangerous, but apparently, we get marks for using them.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to solve this for yourself.  Just one thing:  I think your answer weould be clearer if you say what datatypes your `sedHours` and its `Value` property are.

Comment: The sedHours is a `TSpinEdit` and the `Hours` field is of `integer`. 

 The `sed` is the abbreviation we are instructed to use at school.

Comment: Thanks.  See Update 2 to my answer, which tidies up a loose end about the string conversion exception.